# How to retrieve the test coverage history for a given Java Class?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am using the SonarQube 4.5.7 API. I run SonarQube analysis on full Java codebase overnight (daily).

I want to retrieve test coverage data for a given Java class using the SonarQube API.

When I use following API (sample), it gives me current Test coverage. It doesn't gives me historic test coverage. For ex - what was coverage a week ago or a month ago.

http://sonar-server/api/resources?resource=com.test:module:com.test.service.impl.CheckServiceImpl&metrics=coverage,branch_coverage

**Sample output**

> File: SampleProgram.java
>
> Test Current (today): 99%
>
> Test Current (1 week ago): 92%
>
> Test Current (1 month ago): 96%

Is there any such single API?

Comment: If you want some support you need to upgrade to SonarQube 5.6.6.

Comment: ^ at least 5.6.6. The current version is 6.5. The current LTS is 5.6.6.